# simulate and store specific row to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am generating random numbers between a range. Once the random numbers are computed and appended to a list, I create a dataframe

Here I want to choose the second row

I then want to generate the above logic three times [for now]

Each time I want to store the second row.

```
import pandas as pd
import random
low_Percent = float(60)
high_Percent = float(120)

val_List=[]
val_List1 =[]
# for j in range(3):


for j in range(3):

    for i in range(30):
                num1 = (random.randint(low_Percent, high_Percent))
                num1 = num1/100
                val_List.append(num1)
                df= pd.DataFrame({'rand_num': val_List})
    val_List1.append(df.loc[2:2])
val_List1
```

Now instead of three different random numbers, I am getting the same random number. How is my logic wrong.

```
[   rand_num
 2       1.2,
    rand_num
 2       1.2,
    rand_num
 2       1.2]
```

Is the way I organize my loop wrong. I assume j = 1, then i runs from 1-50 and creates 50 random numbers.
dataframe is created and second row is stored in an array

then J = 2 and the same happens again. So any pointers would be much much appreciated

Adding excel screenshot for added understanding
[image: Second Generated Random Number]

Comment: because `val_list` is static, it doesn't change in order so you're creating a longer dataframe, sure, but the order of the list is the same, hence the 2nd index will be the same whether you do it 3 or 3000 times.

Comment: datanovice. Thanks for the answer. I am trying to understand it since I am a python beginner. I will check back on lists more and check with you if I have any clarifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version which

1. Places the `val_List` into the for loop so―as per @Datanovice―it will actually update the values.
2. Uses `iloc` instead of `loc`: `loc` selects the row with the index '2' which might or might not be the second row depending on the dataframe. `iloc[1]`, on the other hand, will always select the second row.

```py
import pandas as pd
import random

low_Percent = float(60)
high_Percent = float(120)

val_List1 = []

for j in range(3):
    val_List = [] # Placed this inside

    for i in range(30):
        num1 = random.randint(low_Percent, high_Percent)
        num1 = num1 / 100
        val_List.append(num1)
        df = pd.DataFrame({"rand_num": val_List})

    val_List1.append(df.iloc[1].values[0]) # Changed the indexing method

val_List1
```